# Select random N records from each category in DocDB

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to compose a query that will bring N records from each category.

lets say that documents has this structure:

- Id - Unique ID
- Category - String
- Type - String

right now i'm using this query:

`select top 20 * from c where c.category in ('category1','cateogory2') where type='type1'`

I want to be able to fetch 10 records from each category which satisfy there `where` clause.

** I'm using pydocumentdb

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, it seems that a simple query for your needs is like as below.

```
select top 10 * from c where c.category = 'category1' and type='type1'
 union 
select top 10 * from c where c.category = 'category2' and type='type1'
```

However by now, Azure DocumentDb doesn't support `union` operation.

So per my experience, the possible way is create a stored procedure to implement `union` operation for two result sets of querying collection with different parameter value, then call the stored procedure via `pydocumentdb`. Please refer to the official tutorial [DocumentDB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming) to know more details.